# ICA for blind source separation clarification question

Tags: audio, ica, blind-deconvolution

I'm currently trying to implement FastICA for blind source separation from scratch.

The code below does not generate W, the umixing matrix, correctly. When I matrix multiplied the outputs `w1` and `w2` with the mixed signal, the output was not the separated signals. I know the ICA is correct since I had run it on non-audio case, but is there an extra step I'm missing to adapt ICA to blind source separation for audio streams?

Here is the code:

```
import sympy as sy 
# whitening
x = make_mean_zero(x) #make zero mean
dplot = 5
w,v = np.linalg.eig(np.cov(x))
M = (v/sqrt(w)).T
unit_x = dot(M,x) #diagonalize with unit variance
unit_x = unit_x.reshape((2, 1000))

def gen_expect(x):
    mean1 = sum(x[0,])/N
    mean2 = sum(x[1,])/N
    return np.array([[mean1],[mean2]])

df = lambda x: tanh(x)
def ddf(x):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        x[i] = 1/sy.cosh(x[i])**2
    return x

def ica(w):
    i=0
    while True:
        i+=1  
        g1 = gen_expect(df(dot(w,unit_x))*unit_x)
        g2 = gen_expect(ddf(dot(w,unit_x)))
        g1 = np.array([g1[0, 0], g1[1,0]])
        g2 = np.array([g2[0, 0], g2[1,0]])
        w_new = g1 - g2
        w_new /= np.linalg.norm(w_new)
        if abs(np.linalg.norm(w_new-w))<0.000001: 
            break
        w = w_new
    return w
print("now")
w1 = ica(np.random.rand(2))
print("w1")
print(w1)
w2 = array([-w1[1],w1[0]]) # orthog
```

Comment: Maybe the hypethesis of ICA aren't true anymore. In particular, it could be that the mixture is of convolutive nature and not instantaneous...